# persist Entity Framework object instance to xml

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-2

I am using a domain model generated from a db with entity framework. How can i serialize/deserialize an object instance of this domain model to/from xml? can i use the .edmx file for this? any code samples?
thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use the [XmlSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer.aspx) class. There is also the [DataContractSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.datacontractserializer.aspx) which was introduced with WCF. For example if you wanted to serialize an existing object to XML using the `XmlSerializer` class:

```
SomeModel model = ...
var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(SomeModel));
using (var writer = XmlWriter.Create("foo.xml"))
{
    serializer.Serialize(writer, model);
}
```

and to deserialize back a XML to an existing model:

```
var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(SomeModel));
using (var reader = XmlReader.Create("foo.xml"))
{
    var model = (SomeModel)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I use this VB Code to serialize my EF model to Xml :

```
 Try
     Dim serializer = New XmlSerializer(GetType(GestionEDLService.Biens))
     Dim localFolder As StorageFolder = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder
     Dim sampleFile As StorageFile = Await localFolder.CreateFileAsync("dataFile.xml", CreationCollisionOption.OpenIfExists)
     Dim stream As Stream = Await sampleFile.OpenStreamForWriteAsync()

     serializer.Serialize(stream, MyEFModel.MyEntity)

 Catch ex As Exception
     Debug.WriteLine(ex.ToString)
 End Try
```

EDIT: You can also use a DataContractSerializer like this

```
Imports System.Runtime.Serialization

Public Sub WriteToStream(sw As System.IO.Stream)

    Dim dataContractSerializer As New DataContractSerializer(GetType(MyDataSource))

    dataContractSerializer.WriteObject(sw, _MyDataSource)

End Sub

Public Sub ReadFromStream(sr As System.IO.Stream)

    Dim dataContractSerializer As New DataContractSerializer(GetType(MyDataSource))

    _MyDataSource = dataContractSerializer.ReadObject(sr)

End Sub
```

HTH